# Hide App name in Facebookpost

Tags: facebook, hide

I just made my first app for facebook and this app should post sth. in my feed.
Everything is ok but at the top of this message there stands the appname.
How can I hide it?

What will i have to edit?

Comment: You can’t hide the app attribution in normal posts made on user timelines.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I just want it because the user,  who see my post, should think it is directly written by me and not with my posting app.

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out in the comments, this is not possible. The only scenario where the name would not be shown to regular users is if you're posting as a page, then the name is only visible to Page Admins but not regular users.